# section overlaps on another section

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with positioning, everything works fine except the last section **contactform**.
The problem is that when I zoom in, the **contactform** overlaps on **services** section.
Here's the code:

```css
.services {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160vh;
  margin: 100px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.services-content {
  /* position: relative; */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.services-content h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.content-row-one {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.row-one {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.quality-management {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.quality-management h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.testing-calibration {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.testing-calibration h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.medical-devices {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.medical-devices h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content-row-two {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.row-two {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.lead-auditor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.lead-auditor h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.project-management {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.project-management h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.quality-assurance {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.quality-assurance h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content-row-three {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.row-three {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.document-management {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.document-management h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.contactform {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
}

.contact {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.contact-content {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center;
  text-align: center; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* position: absolute; */
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.contact-column-one {
  width: 33%;
  height: 50%;
}

.contact-column-one .location i {
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-column-one .location i:hover{
  color: rgb(19, 112, 233);
  transition: .5s;
}

.contact-column-one h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.contact-column-two {
  width: 33%;
  height: 50%;
}

.contact-column-two .phone i {
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-column-two .phone i:hover {
  color: rgb(19, 112, 233);
  transition: .5s;
}

.contact-column-two h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.contact-column-three {
  width: 33%;
  height: 50%;
}

.contact-column-three .email i {
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-column-three .email i:hover {
  color: rgb(19, 112, 233);
  transition: .5s;
}

.contact-column-three h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="services" id="services">
        <div class="services-content">
            <h1>OUR SERVICES</h1>
            <div class="content-row-one">
                <div class="row-one">
                    <div class="quality-management">
                        <h6>1. Quality Management Systems according to ISO 9000 2015</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="testing-calibration">
                        <h6>2. Quality Management Systems for Testing and Calibration Laboratories</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="medical-devices">
                        <h6>3. Quality Management for Medical Devices according to ISO 13485</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-row-two">
                <div class="row-two">
                    <div class="lead-auditor">
                        <h6>4. Lead Auditor according to ISO 9001</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-management">
                        <h6>5. Project Management</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quality-assurance">
                        <h6>6. Quality Assurance</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-row-three">
                <div class="row-three">
                    <div class="document-management">
                        <h6>7. Document Management with SharePoint Server</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="contactform" id="contactform">
            <div class="contact">
                <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
                <div class="contact-content">
                    <div class="contact-column-one">
                        <span class="location">
                            <i class="material-icons">
                                place
                            </i>
                        </span>
                        <h1>ADDRESS</h1>
                        <p>Address</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-column-two">
                        <span class="phone">
                            <i class="material-icons">
                                phone
                            </i>
                        </span>
                        <h1>PHONE</h1>
                        <p>Phone Number</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-column-three">
                        <span class="email">
                            <i class="material-icons">
                                email
                            </i>
                        </span>
                        <h1>EMAIL</h1>
                        <p>Email</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I've tried removing position, from absolute to relative and vice versa, but nothing changed.
If you need more code or explanation please feel free to ask.
Thank you for your time!

Here's a photo:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have a fixed `height` for `.services` it will always overlap when the content total height higher than `.services height`, instead you could use `min-height` so if the content height less than `160vh` the height will remain `160vh` but if the content height more than `160vh` then `.services height` will grow corresponding to the content.

```css
.services {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 160vh;
  margin: 100px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.services-content {
  /* position: relative; */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.services-content h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.content-row-one {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.row-one {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.quality-management {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.quality-management h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.testing-calibration {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.testing-calibration h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.medical-devices {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.medical-devices h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content-row-two {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.row-two {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.lead-auditor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.lead-auditor h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.project-management {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.project-management h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.quality-assurance {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.quality-assurance h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content-row-three {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.row-three {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.document-management {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
}

.document-management h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.contactform {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
}

.contact {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.contact-content {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center;
  text-align: center; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* position: absolute; */
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.contact-column-one {
  width: 33%;
  height: 50%;
}

.contact-column-one .location i {
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-column-one .location i:hover{
  color: rgb(19, 112, 233);
  transition: .5s;
}

.contact-column-one h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.contact-column-two {
  width: 33%;
  height: 50%;
}

.contact-column-two .phone i {
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-column-two .phone i:hover {
  color: rgb(19, 112, 233);
  transition: .5s;
}

.contact-column-two h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.contact-column-three {
  width: 33%;
  height: 50%;
}

.contact-column-three .email i {
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-column-three .email i:hover {
  color: rgb(19, 112, 233);
  transition: .5s;
}

.contact-column-three h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="services" id="services">
        <div class="services-content">
            <h1>OUR SERVICES</h1>
            <div class="content-row-one">
                <div class="row-one">
                    <div class="quality-management">
                        <h6>1. Quality Management Systems according to ISO 9000 2015</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="testing-calibration">
                        <h6>2. Quality Management Systems for Testing and Calibration Laboratories</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="medical-devices">
                        <h6>3. Quality Management for Medical Devices according to ISO 13485</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-row-two">
                <div class="row-two">
                    <div class="lead-auditor">
                        <h6>4. Lead Auditor according to ISO 9001</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-management">
                        <h6>5. Project Management</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quality-assurance">
                        <h6>6. Quality Assurance</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-row-three">
                <div class="row-three">
                    <div class="document-management">
                        <h6>7. Document Management with SharePoint Server</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In omnis magni praesentium velit sit
                            sapiente sed magnam accusamus quisquam, maxime rem! Adipisci, quisquam? Dolor fugiat dolores
                            porro
                            quo perferendis accusamus!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="contactform" id="contactform">
            <div class="contact">
                <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
                <div class="contact-content">
                    <div class="contact-column-one">
                        <span class="location">
                            <i class="material-icons">
                                place
                            </i>
                        </span>
                        <h1>ADDRESS</h1>
                        <p>Address</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-column-two">
                        <span class="phone">
                            <i class="material-icons">
                                phone
                            </i>
                        </span>
                        <h1>PHONE</h1>
                        <p>Phone Number</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-column-three">
                        <span class="email">
                            <i class="material-icons">
                                email
                            </i>
                        </span>
                        <h1>EMAIL</h1>
                        <p>Email</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked smoothly! And about the paragraphs, they overlap into each other too, what do you think is the best solution for it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue coming from the same reason, you have a fixed `height` for rows as well as its children and it's not a good practice to give fixed `height` to a text container, remove all 'height' property from the above classes and you will get rid of the overlapping

Answer (score 0):

You should set `height: auto;`

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qhsygpb5/

Explanation: when you set "height: 200px" element height will be 200px no matter how much content contains. Other solution is to add "overflow:hidden;" but than you will not see all content if there is not room. Also you can add "overflow: scroll;" if you want to scroll the content within 200px height.